# Why does the `anova` function in R only report results for one factor only?

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run an ANOVA model in R, with two factors, at 3 levels each. The first factor has levels `1,2,3` and the second factor has levels `X,Y,Z`. The following shows the stucture:

```
    V1   V2
1    1    X
2    2    X
3    3    X
4    1    Y
5    2    Y
6    3    Y
7    1    Z
8    2    Z
9    3    Z
```

Here is example code with a simulated response:

```
factorA <- as.factor(rep(c("1","2","3"),3))
factorB <- as.factor(rep(c("X","Y","Z"),3))
response <- rnorm(9)
anova(lm(response ~ factorA + factorB))
```

When I run the above, I get the following output:

```
    Analysis of Variance Table

Response: response
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
factorA    2  2.1827  1.0914   0.545 0.6061
Residuals  6 12.0148  2.0025
```

Is there a reason factorB doesn't show?

Comment: This is due to a coding error. Your factorA and factorB are exactly the same (and not as your proposed structure), so `lm` drops the second one. Try `factorB <- as.factor(rep(c("X","Y","Z"),each=3))` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!